# Sticky tab menu that actually scrolls the page vertically?

Tags: website-design, tabs, scrolling

Not sure if the title is clear enough but i'm looking for examples and thoughts on this type of components. I looked through some single page websites but couldn't find what I was looking for right away. What are your thoughts on tab-like menus usually on top of a page that actually vertically scrolls you to the relative section and are there any well executed examples that you can think of in a website? Thanks!

Comment: Related is also the "dot navigation". See https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/41349/what-is-the-purpose-and-origin-of-in-page-navigation and https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/navigationV.html

Answer (score 1):

I see this sometimes on single-page applications (e.g. portfolios, small businesses) with a horizontal menu that scrolls to the part of the content when you click the corresponding menu item. I usually find it a bit of a waste because the pages seem to be short and I have to click all menu items to see if there is some content that is not on the page (e.g. a contact form).

This [bootstrap demo](https://startbootstrap.com/previews/scrolling-nav/) is a good illustration even though it has extreme scroll inertia.

Comment: Thank you! I agree that it can be a bit confusing when it's the main navigation like the example you provided. I'm thinking of using it not as the primary navigation but for navigating in a long page full of charts & tables. So the menu items will be the chart titles only and I'm hoping that won't cause the problem you pointed out. The main navigation is a sidebar at the left side of the screen from where you can reach the page i'm talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nifty vertical tabs (left side bar) implementation which I found on cssninja: https://vulk.cssninja.io/blocks/

It's not on top. However, within the same theme, you can also find a hero-footer that becomes a tabbed-based navigation bar  after you scroll implementation:

https://vulk.cssninja.io/blocks/navtabs

Hope you found what you are looking for! I believe this theme is Bulma-based but they may have another version for Tailwind that's similar.